# Rails messaging system (fetch received messages)

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a messaging system for Owner and Renter to communicate. Owner owns a Vehicle. 
If Renter has any questions he can send a Message.

NB! A **new** Discussion is created **automatically** along with posted Message.

Discussion has many Messages.

Discussion has following sturcture: (id, title, vehicle_id, user_id)
Message has following structure: (id, text, discussion_id, user_id)

It was pretty easy to fetch all messages, **sent** by the User:

in User class:

```
has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

but now I can't find out how to fetch all **received** messages for the User - user.received_messages

It, basically, means that it is necessary to look through all the Discussions that either belong to the User (he created that discussion and there are messages which don't belong to him) or the Discussions that belong to his Vehicle (someone else created this discussion and Discussion.user_id == Message.user_id).

Can someone help me out with this one ? Cannot figure out how to make this association query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, using `:finder_sql` parameter for the `has_many` association. Just raw SQL-query with the algorithm, I've described in my question.